# Help of solving a complex integral

Tags: integration

I encounter a complex integral that is hard for me, i.e.,

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{{\mathbb R^2}} {\frac{1}{{\left( {{{\left( {{x^2} + {y^2}} \right)}^{\frac{\alpha }{2}}} + {T_1}} \right)\left( {{{\left( {{{\left( {x - D} \right)}^2} + {y^2}} \right)}^{\frac{\alpha }{2}}} + {T_2}} \right)}}dx} dy
\end{equation}
By using polar coordinate transformation, it follows that
\begin{equation}2\int\limits_0^\infty  {\int\limits_0^\pi  {\frac{r}{{\left( {{r^\alpha } + {T_1}} \right)\left( {{{\left( {{r^2} + {D^2} - 2Dr\cos \left( \theta  \right)} \right)}^{\frac{\alpha }{2}}} + {T_2}} \right)}}d\theta } dr} 
\end{equation}
where $T_1$, $T_2$ and $D$ are all positive. I would greatly appreciate your suggestions and help.

Comment: Some context could be useful, like where did you face this integral and what are your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I have added the original problem.